# What formula should I use to pull

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

What Excel formula can I write so it will look for the same project in  Column B  in Column I and place the  YTD matching the project from Column J in Column C in the table below?

```
A            B               I         J
Name       Project         Project   YTD
Junior     7500             9100     5000
Luis       9100             7500     15000
Danny      2000             0500     1000 
Jose       1000             1000     250
Lina       0500             2000     7505
```

Answer (score 1):

Using <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> would be better if you have access to **`Excel 2021/MS365`**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(B2:B6&"",I2:I6,J2:J6,"Not Found")
```

---

Suggested to use <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> because of several reasons, here are some outlined below:

- Exact match is the default.
- Integer-based third argument of VLOOKUP is now a proper reference.
- IFNA is built-in to handle missing values.
- `XLOOKUP()` has no problem going to the left.
- `XLOOKUP()` can do `HLOOKUP()`.
- It can return a cell reference if the `XLOOKUP()` is next to a colon such as `XLOOKUP();XLOOKUP()`
- It can perform a two-way match like `INDEX(,MATCH,MATCH)` does.
- It can find the last match by searching from the bottom.
- It can find next-smaller or next-larger match without sorting the table.

---

The syntax of <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> read here more from **[MSFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)** documentations. There are 5/6 examples shown as well.

```
=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode], [search_mode])
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can combine IFNA, INDEX and MATCH functions to retrive the result(s). Try the following formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($J$2:$J$6,MATCH(B2,$I$2:$I$6,0)),"")
```

[image]

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` will do what you want.

In cell C2 enter this forumula:
`=VLOOKUP(B2,$I$2:$J$6,2,FALSE)`

Then copy that down to the rest of the cells in Col C.

[image]

`VLOOKUP` will match the value from Col B (first parameter of the forumla) to a value in Col I (the left-most column of the lookup range).

`$I$2:$J$6` is the lookup range, where your lookup values are.  The `$` are very important as they indicate to use the same lookup range when copying the formula to cells in Col C.

The 2 in the 3rd parameter tells Excel to return the value from the 2nd column of the lookup range.

False (default for the 4th parameter) says to use an exact match.